# Microsoft Sharepoint deployment issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm following the Microsoft docs for SPFx `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page`
and I am not able to deploy the app properly. Well it deploys, even gets listed as deployed (the WebPart), but it will not show up when I try to modify pages.
Has anyone experienced this before?
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either add your app manually to the site, or set `"skipFeatureDeployment": true,` in `config\package-solution.json` for the web part to be available.

Note, the last method deploys the app to all sites and thus makes the web part available for adding across your whole tenant.

Comment: How do I manually add the app to the site? I'll try the second method as well, I think it's alright if it's available across the entire tenant. Thank you

Comment: I did the second part, it still says `tenant deployed: no` under SharePoint-admin. I also checked my SharePoint site, I don't see the webpart.

Comment: You need to click "Add an app" from the settings menu or from "Add.." on the home page. App should be one of the choices.

Comment: I have done that, and that should let me select the App from what I have uploaded on SharePoint, but I don't see that option. Unless there is another way, would you be able to send a screengrab possibly if so?

Comment: Are there other custom apps available in your tenant? If you could share your solution (or at least the config folder + manifest) it might be easier to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: There are no custom web apps, this is the only one. though I tried to install a SharePoint web part and use it, and I was able to see/use it. Would you still be able to take a look at the config folder and manifest? I can post it if you are still willing to!

Comment: Sure, no problem